# Work Item discussion is not being added when rerunning tool

Tags: azure-devops-migration-tools

After migrating the work items from one azure devops environment to another.  When rerunning the tool, the tool updates the related links but the discussions are not updating. How can we move over new discussions from the old environment?

Answer (score 0):

Discussions are not migrated as they are part of the REST API, and the Azure DevOps Migration Tools use the ObjectModel...

https://nkdagility.github.io/azure-devops-migration-tools/